# LaunchAPEX.jsp couldn't be launched from IE 11 but can be launched from chrome or mozilla

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer

I am calling an APEX page from oracle EBS by launching LaunchAPEX.jsp. In Chrome and Mozilla, the page is launched properly and the new APEX window pops up. But in Internet explorer, it is not launched properly. I just get a blank window.

Can somebody help me and let me know how can I get my Internet explorer work properly.

I tried following methods, but none of them helps :
1. Added the website in Compatibility setting.
2. Enabled Active scripting under Security Settings of IE
3. Turned off the pop up blocker.

Thanks,
abha

Comment: Try to check the console for any error or warning message. If that site is already hosted and if possible than try to share the URL for testing. Without checking the code, We cannot find the cause for this issue. for testing, Try to create a new sample project and try to load it in IE 11 to check whether it works or not. If possible for you than try to provide a sample code and steps to produce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by unchecking the "Display intranet sites in compatibility View" in Compatibility view settings.
Hope this helps somebody !

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved your issue and posted the answer. I suggest you to mark that answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.